# R : How to find data only within 1 standard deviation

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector of data and it is normally distributed. 
I get a clear bell shape from the chart.

Question is how do I get data only belonging to 1sd (68% of data)

Comment: Googled for half hour. watched few youtube videos. Finally I am here for help : P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you vector is `x`, you can use `x[abs(x - mean(x)) < sd(x)]` to extract data distributed around 1 standard error of the mean.

An alternative method (maybe more preferred) is `x[abs(scale(x)) < 1]`, where `scale(x)` gives standardized / normalized `x`.

Comment: I would just write "<=" instead of "<": 
x[abs(x - mean(x)) <= sd(x)]